# How to add a class to current clicked path?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot manage to add a class to the clicked polygon path, the following gives me the correct click on the path but it is not adding the class

```
  function zoomToFeatureB(e) {
    e.target.setAttribute("class", "active");
  }

  function onEachFeatureB(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: zoomToFeatureB
    });
  }
```

Comment: try `$(e.target).addClass("active");`

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks, just answered my own solution actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to do it like this:

```
  function zoomToFeatureB(e) {
     this.getElement().classList.add('active');
  }

  function onEachFeatureB(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: zoomToFeatureB
    });
  }
```

Comment: `this` might not work as expected. If you have multiple elements in `layer`, and one of them gets clicked, the class will be added to that element. I prefer `e.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jquery, then try the following

```
function zoomToFeatureB(e) 
{
   $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

or

```
function zoomToFeatureB(e) 
{
   $(e.target).addClass("active");
}
```

for better browser compatibility than [classList.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility)